# How to create sequencediagram in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml, sequence-diagram

I would like to create a sequencediagram from a visual studio 2010 c# solution. Just run the code. Is there any way to create that without having visual studio ultimate 2010?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409389.aspx

edit: Or is there any other tool? 1 project with 3 files .cs and a few classes.

edit: **is nobody creating sequencediagrams from code?**

Comment: *Using* Visual Studio? No. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

Comment: can you post an answer so i can close with your solution?

Comment: I did, thanks... I forgot about the question, but since it's still essentially unanswered, I'll dig into it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Using* Visual Studio? No. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

Comment: I searched a bit and couldn't find *free* tool, however there's bunch of commercial products (i guess ~200-300$)